# Interpreting Rprofile Output: What is this <Anonymous> Function?

Tags: r, profiling, anonymous-function

So I have a big function that runs a MCMC algorithm. I believe most of the
expensive operations are multiplications of large matrices, but this `Rprof` output is rather perplexing.

```
$by.self
                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"<Anonymous>"      328.90    81.84     329.34     81.95
"fprod"             46.16    11.49     376.02     93.57
"Dikin_Walk"         7.42     1.85     401.32     99.86
"as.vector"          5.98     1.49      57.56     14.32
".External"          2.54     0.63       2.54      0.63
"-"                  1.84     0.46       1.84      0.46
"H_x"                1.16     0.29     225.82     56.19
"fcrossprod"         1.14     0.28     226.12     56.27
```

Edit: Here are the 3 functions which I define within my big wrapper function:

```
## first, augment A | b 
A_b <- cbind (b, A)

## H(x) is the hessian
H_x <- function(x) {
  D <- as.vector(1/(A_b[,1] - fprod(A_b[,-1], x)))
  D_squared <- fdiag(D^2)
  return(fcrossprod(A, fprod(D_squared, A)))  
}

## D(x) is the diagonalized matrix of the log-barrier function of Ax <= b
D_x <- function(x) {

  D <- as.vector(1/(A_b[,1] - fprod(A_b[,-1], x)))
  return(fdiag(D))
} 

## checks whether a point z is in Ellip(x)
ellipsoid <- function(z, x) {

  ## as.numeric converts the expression into an atom, so we get boolean
  return( as.numeric(fcrossprod(z-x, fprod(H_x(x), (z-x)))) <= r^2)

}
```

The `fdiag` , `fcrossprod`, and `fprod` are all `RcppArmEigen` versions of their `R` counterparts. I used them because they are substantially faster.

The main algorithm:

```
> for (i in 1:n) {
>   
>    zeta <- rnorm(length(b), 0, 1)
>    zeta <- r * zeta / sqrt(as.numeric(fcrossprod(zeta,zeta)))
>  
>    rhs <- fcrossprod(A, fprod(D_x(current.point), zeta))
>    
>    ## DONE
>    
>    y <- fprod(fsolve(H_x(current.point)), rhs) 
>    y <- y + current.point
>    
>
>    while(!ellipsoid(current.point, y)) {
>    zeta <- rnorm(length(b), 0, 1)
>      
>     ## normalise to be on the m- unit sphere
>     ## and then compute lhs as a m-vector
>     zeta <- r * zeta / sqrt(sum(zeta * zeta))
>     
>     
>     rhs <- fcrossprod(A, fprod(D_x(current.point), zeta))
>     
>     ## 
>     y <- fprod(fsolve(H_x(current.point)), rhs)  
>     y <- y + current.point
>     
>
>     if(ellipsoid(current.point, y)) {
>      
>       probability <- min(1, sqrt(fdet(fprod(fsolve(H_x(current.point)),H_x(y))      )))
>        
>        
>       bool <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1, prob = c(probability, 1-?>probability))
>       if(bool) {
>         break
>       } 
>     }
>   }
```

And here is the `by.total` output:

```
$by.total
                      total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"Dikin_Walk"              401.32     99.86      7.42     1.85
"fprod"                   376.02     93.57     46.16    11.49
"<Anonymous>"             329.34     81.95    328.90    81.84
"cbind"                   268.58     66.83      0.04     0.01
"fcrossprod"              226.12     56.27      1.14     0.28
"H_x"                     225.82     56.19      1.16     0.29
"fsolve"                  203.82     50.72      0.14     0.03
"ellipsoid"               126.30     31.43      0.56     0.14
"fdet"                     64.84     16.13      0.02     0.00
"as.vector"                57.56     14.32      5.98     1.49
"fdiag"                    35.68      8.88      0.50     0.12
```

`fprod` is defined as:

```
prodCpp <- 'typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> MapMatd;
const MapMatd B(as<MapMatd>(BB));
const MapMatd C(as<MapMatd>(CC));
return wrap(B * C);'

fprod <- cxxfunction(signature(BB = "matrix", CC = "matrix"),
                      prodCpp, "RcppEigen")
```

Comment: Is your question if that is the function that is referred to as <Anonymous> or is it why would that function take up so much time?

Comment: I think it's just saying anonymous because you don't name the function.

Comment: @Dason Sorry, I guess my question is why is this anonymous function taking so long. There is no other anonymous function in my code.

Comment: @Roland `rowSums` computes the sum of each row, so that code wouldn't be computing the dot product of row-i of A with x?

Comment: I don't see an anonymous function in the code. It must be called within one of the other functions. Look at the "by.total"  output.

Comment: @Roland I editted the by.total output. The Dikin_Walk is my big wrapper function, and it is self_contained (other than the `fprod`, `fcrossprod` stuff)

Comment: Well, look at the definition of `fprod`. It look like it calls an anonymous function.

Comment: @Roland I posted the definition for `fprod`. I think `fprod` "takes so long" because the way I called it in my code was through `fprod( some other function call)`. If you look at the `by.self` code, `fprod` doesn't take that long.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your time is spent with matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Anonymous>` refers to an anonymous (unnamed) function. If you are running such a function in a loop, most of the time will typically be spent in this function.

Apparently `A_b` is a matrix and `x` a vector. Use matrix algebra instead of a loop:

```
A_b <- matrix(1:16, 4)
x <- 1:3
D <- apply(A_b, 1, function(row) {1 / (row[1] - sum(row[-1] * x))})

D1 <- as.vector(1/(A_b[,1] - A_b[,-1] %*% x))

identical (D, D1)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Edit:**

The anonymous function is in the Rcpp magic of `fprod`:

```
B <- matrix(rnorm(1e6),1e3)
C <- matrix(rnorm(1e6),1e3)

Rprof()
for (i in 1:30) BC <- fprod(B, C)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
#$by.self
#              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"<Anonymous>"      4.24      100       4.24       100
#
#$by.total
#              total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
#"<Anonymous>"       4.24       100      4.24      100
#"fprod"             4.24       100      0.00        0
#
#$sample.interval
#[1] 0.02
#
#$sampling.time
#[1] 4.24
```

Most of your time is spent with matrix multiplication. You might benefit from an optimized BLAS, e.g., you could try OpenBLAS.

Comment: I switched it, but I think I actually interpreted the <Anonymous> function wrong: 

`$by.self
                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"<Anonymous>"      122.94    96.97     122.94     96.97`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not without seeing more code. I think what you have shown might actually be the "FUN" in the profiling output since that's the parameter of `apply` to which the function is passed. There must be an anonymous function somewhere else in your code. Since I don't have that code I can't help you with finding it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'll post an edit right now, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: I see. Good to know that most of the time is spent where it should be spending. Thank you so much for all this help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ignore "self time", because "total time" is inclusive of that plus callees.
If you are spending any time that you don't need to, you are far more likely to be doing it by calling functions than by crunching.**

Second, don't even look at that.
Rprofile produces a file of stack traces.
Just look at several of those, selected at random.
If a function is responsible for 80% of time, you will see it on roughly 4 out of 5 of stack traces.
What's more, you will see who is calling it, and you will see who it is calling, to cause that time to be spent.
Simple numbers do not tell you that.
Sorting the stack traces also does not tell you that.

It would be even better if it gave line numbers at which the calls were made, but it doesn't.
Even so, just showing the functions is still pretty useful.

** Profilers only display "self time" because they always have, and because all the others do it, and few people have woken up to the fact that it's just a distraction. If a function is at the terminus of a stack trace, it's in "self time". Either way it's in "inclusive time".